# Extending a function to the profinite completion of the integers

Tags: profinite-groups

I am trying to see if the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
 f(n) = \frac{1}{n-z}
$$
for some $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R}$ can be continuosly extended to the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, denoted by $\hat {\mathbb{Z}}$. Since $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is compact this is possible if and only if this function is uniformly continuous in the metric that induces the topology of $\mathbb{\hat{Z}}$, i.e.
$$
d(n,m)= \inf\  \{ k^{-1} \mid n - m = 0 \mod k!\}.
$$

I have been able to prove that if $d(n,m)$ is small and $d(n,0) \not= d(m,0)$ then $\lvert f(n) - f(m) \rvert$ is small, but I don't have a clue for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the profinite topology, $3 + n! \to 3$, as $n\to \infty$, but
$$ f ( 3 + n!) \to 0 \not= f(3).$$
So $f$ is not continuous.